How to get all vertices which has at least one neighbour in gremlin?
I tried to use filter to get all vertices which has at least one neighbour in gremlin, but get error, did I mis-use filter function? Thanks
g.V().hasLabel("Customer", "Loan", "Account", "CreditCard").filter(both().hasNext())


hasNext() is a terminal step.  It is only meant to be used at the end of a query, not within the query:  https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps
You can achieve what you're looking for by doing something like:
g.V().hasLabel("Customer", "Loan", "Account","CreditCard").
    where(bothE().count().is(gt(0)))

If issuing this using one of the Gremlin clients, you'll need to end this with next(), toList() or some other Terminal step to send the query to your database and fetch a result.
If you're looking for a good resource to use in learning Gremlin, I highly suggest looking at:  https://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html
